# Mongoose not saving a model with await and try/catch block

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, socket.io

I create a Game model with correct attributes and try to save it with an *await* in a try/catch block, but it does not save and does not catch the error.

```
socket.on('create-game',async (nickName)=>{
        try{
            const quotableData = await QuotableAPI();
            let game = new Game();
            game.words = quotableData;
            let player = {
                socketID : socket.id,
                isPartyLeader : true,
                nickName
            }
            game.players.push(player);
            game = await game.save();
            const gameID = game._id.toString();
            socket.join(gameID);
            io.to(gameID).emit('updateGame',game);
        } catch (err) {
            console.log(err);     
        }
    });
```

If I take away the *await*, it works (the code above), however later on in my code (shown below), when I try to find this specific game with its id by using the Game.findbyId() method, I am unable to find it.

```
socket.on('join-game',async ({gameID : _id,nickName})=>{
    try{
        let game = await Game.findById(_id);
        if(game.isOpen){
            const gameID = game._id.toString();
            socket.join(gameID);
            let player = {
                socketID : socket.id,
                nickName
            }
            game.players.push(player);
            game = await game.save();
            io.to(gameID).emit('updateGame',game);
        }
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

EDIT: I was following a tutorial and they did not write their own save() function so I assumed it was already implemented when creating the model.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const PlayerSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    currentWordIndex : {
        type: Number,
        default : 0
    },
    socketID : {type : String},
    isPartyLeader : {type : Boolean,default : false},
    WPM : {type : Number, default: -1},
    nickName : {type : String}
});

const GameSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    words : [{type : String}],
    isOpen : {type : Boolean,default : true},
    isOver : {type : Boolean,default : false},
    players : [PlayerSchema],
    startTime : {type : Number}
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Game',GameSchema);
```

EDIT 2: Installing MongoDB solved everything. I am so sad I spent ~day trying to debug this.

Comment: it may be useful to see the Game class definition (is that something your wrote?) at least the `save` method

Comment: For mongoose, when you create a schema are you supposed to create your own save method?

Comment: no idea, so your Game class extends some mongoose class? Sorry, I see the edit now

Comment: Kind of, from my interpretation, mongoose is a library that allows you to create models to which you can create instances of the model and add/query/delete/ them to your database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `findbyid` method only works with the objectId which will be automatically created by MongoDB when a document is saved. You've to use `find` method if you're using custom creteria.

Comment: When I installed MongoDB, everything started to work. In the tutorial I was watching, the person did not install MongoDB, so I was wondering if you did need to if you are using mongoose.

Comment: The possibility is that either that person has mongodb installed already or the person is using a remote instance like on mongodb atals. Mongoose is a lib that helps you to connect to the DB, it's not the DB itself.

Comment: Can you link us to the tutorial as well?

Comment: Yea, they did not mention anything about MongoDB at all. Here's the link: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YHmrPd5ZIuo

Comment: As can be seen at 7:04 of the video. The person is connecting to a 'local' instance of mongodb. The connection url is 'mongodb://localhost:27017/typeracertutorial'. The localhost here indicates that the person has installed mongodb locally. If the person didnt mention how to install mongodb, you can find many tutorials about it on youtube. For example this one here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-56x56UppqQ&t=1471s&ab_channel=TraversyMedia for mac and this one here for windows https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pWbMrx5rVBE&ab_channel=TraversyMedia